# Find rows in which a column value only occurs once (Single-Sided Entries in Double Entry accounting system)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of bank transactions, AccountTransaction, and rows with for e.g.

| Amount | Payee_Name | Transaction_ID | Is_Corresponding_Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69.00 | Bob Jones | 1 | 1 |
| -69.00 | Bob Jones | 1 | 0 |
| 25.00 | Bill | 2 | 1 |
| -25.00 | Bill | 2 | 0 |
| 297.00 | Sally | 3 | 1 |
| -5.00 | Ted | 4 | 1 |
| 2.50 | Ted | 4 | 0 |
| 2.50 | Ted | 4 | 0 |

How do I select only (all) TS like Sally's where the Transaction ID only occurs once?

Bonus points: How do I select TS like Ted's where the sum of all Is_Corresponding_Transaction = 0 != the sum of Is_Corresponding_Transaction = 1 for a given TS_ID?

I was looking and found a Group by or where not exists, but couldn't figure out how to get that to work

Here's an e.g. of what I tried:

```sql
select 
Full_Name, amount, a.Posted_Date,a.Payee_Name, a.Memo, Accounts.Account_Name
from AccountTransaction a
left join Accounts on Accounts.Account_Code = a.Account_Code
left join users on a.UserId = users.UserId
where not exists (select 1 from AccountTransaction b where a.Transaction_ID = b.Transaction_ID having count(*)>1)
and a.Pending= 0
ORDER by a.Posted_Date desc
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: Use a windowed sum to calculate the sum for each client.

Comment: Window aggregations will give you the method. Which question are you actually asking here?

Comment: I think the way you really need to frame this is that Transaction_ID 3 **does not sum to 0**. As an example: the general ledger system maintains an accounting for `Ted`, where we make two $2.50 payments. It also has a special "Cash" account. When we pay Ted $2.50 twice, we need to also reflect that in the cash account... it has to reduce by $5. **BOTH** transactions are relevant.  This is standard accounting practice: _every transaction_ must _always_ sum to zero.

Comment: As an addendum... it's not enough to have an "Is corresponding transaction" column. You also need a GL Account Number indicating what account to use for each part of the transaction.

Comment: Simply: COUNT and GROUPBY

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... HAVING   COUNT() = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Stu's comment.  Here is one option that uses the window function

```
with cte as (
Select * 
      ,NetSum = sum(Amount) over (partition by Transaction_ID)
      ,NetCnt = sum(1)      over (partition by Transaction_ID)
 From YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte 
 Where NetSum<>0 
    or NetCnt<>2
```